# DataGridViewer how to get value of cell in newly selected row

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

Good day,

I am trying to create a media player in vb.net. I have a sql local database setup with meta data of certain users songs. They have been displayed in the DataGridViewer in my form to dislay to the user the songs they can play. Im now wanting to implement a procedure that can return the value of "SONG_NAME" in the users selected row when the grid is clicked.

[DataGrid Viewer Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAfDd.png)

The settings of my DataGridViewer have multiselect off and the selection mode to Full row select. I have done some research but have found little outlining how to fetch the value of a certain column in the selection. Any help would be greatly appreciated as i am fairly new to Vb.net.

Comment: Do you mean that when you click the data grid view, you want to get the value in the column or are you clicking a button to get the value?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code can help

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                                ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
                                Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    MessageBox.Show(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString)
End Sub
```